# in WebGpu, what is the stride and size of a Boolean?

Tags: webgpu

In the [memory layout](https://www.w3.org/TR/WGSL/#alignment-and-size) section in the WebGPU shading language, alignment and size are specified for many primitive types, vectors, arrays and matrices,
but nothing is mentioned for `bool`.

also in the [type definitions](https://www.w3.org/TR/WGSL/#bool-type), int/float types are detailed about what memory they use and how, while for `bool`, the spec only mentions it has 2 values: `true` and `false`

How should the `bool` type actually be implemented (bitwise), and what stride and size does it have in structs?

Comment: Just a guess: bool corresponds to the smallest possible int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in WGSL, at least version 1, there is no `bool` type that you can pass into/out of a shader so in general so there is no "memory layout" for a bool. You only need to know the size for computing things like workgroup storage size limits, not for memory layout

You can see this if you try to use them:

```js
async function main() {
  const adapter = await navigator.gpu?.requestAdapter();
  const device = await adapter?.requestDevice();
  if (!device) {
    fail('need a browser that supports WebGPU');
    return;
  }

  const codes = [
    `
      @group(0) @binding(0) var<uniform> b: bool;
    `,
    `
      @group(0) @binding(0) var<storage> b: bool;
    `,
    `
      struct Uni {
        b: bool,
      };
      @group(0) @binding(0) var<uniform> u: Uni;
    `,
    `
      struct Uni {
        b: bool,
      };
      @group(0) @binding(0) var<storage> u: Uni;
    `,
  ];

  for (const code of codes) {
    const module = device.createShaderModule({code});
    const info = await module.getCompilationInfo();
    log('=========');
    log(code);
    log('-----');
    for (const msg of info.messages) {
      log(msg.message);
    }
  }
}

function log(...args) {
  const elem = document.createElement('pre');
  elem.textContent = args.join(' ');
  document.body.appendChild(elem);
}

main();
```

```css
pre { margin: 0; }
```

In Chrome v120 the code above produces these error messages

```
=========

      @group(0) @binding(0) var<uniform> b: bool;
    
-----
Type 'bool' cannot be used in address space 'uniform' as it is non-host-shareable
while instantiating 'var' b
=========

      @group(0) @binding(0) var<storage> b: bool;
    
-----
Type 'bool' cannot be used in address space 'storage' as it is non-host-shareable
while instantiating 'var' b
=========

      struct Uni {
        b: bool,
      };
      @group(0) @binding(0) var<uniform> u: Uni;
    
-----
Type 'bool' cannot be used in address space 'uniform' as it is non-host-shareable
while analyzing structure member Uni.b
while instantiating 'var' u
=========

      struct Uni {
        b: bool,
      };
      @group(0) @binding(0) var<storage> u: Uni;
    
-----
Type 'bool' cannot be used in address space 'storage' as it is non-host-shareable
while analyzing structure member Uni.b
while instantiating 'var' u
```

If you want to pass bool values into your shader you'll have to pass them in via some other format and convert them in the shader. For example, you could pass 32 bits as a `u32` and convert each bit to a bool in the shader.

```
@group(0) @binding(0) var<uniform> thirtyTwoBools: u32;
...
let b0 = bool(thirtyTwoBools & 0x01);
let b1 = bool(thirtyTwoBools & 0x02);
...
```

Or you could pass one `u32` per bool and convert in the shader.

```
@group(0) @binding(0) var<uniform> oneBool: u32;
...
let b0 = bool(oneBool);
```

Or pass four bool as bytes per u32

```
@group(0) @binding(0) var<uniform> fourBoolsAsBytes: u32;
...
let b0 = bool(fourBoolsAsBytes & 0xFF);
let b1 = bool(fourBoolsAsBytes & 0xFF00);
let b2 = bool(fourBoolsAsBytes & 0xFF0000);
...
```

etc...

Answer (score 1):

From a table on that page, it seems like a bool is 1 byte

[image]

https://www.w3.org/TR/WGSL/#limits

I went through every ctrl/cmd+f search of "bool" and these are the only two references I see to bools that mention a size in bytes

Comment: There is no "memory layout" for `bool` because you can't pass a `bool` into or out-of WebGPU, at least in version 1.